# Генерирование матрицы (C++)

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Есть задание: реализовать программу, которая меняет местами последнюю строку и первый столбик квадратной матрицы.
Ниже, мой код. В нем, я добился нормальной генерации матрицы на заданных пользователем промежутках и размерах матрицы. Но как поменять местами строку и столбик - я не знаю. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
setlocale(0, "");
const int M = 10;
const int N = 10;
int Q[M][N];
int m, n, a, b;
printf("\n\tEnter m, n: ");
scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
if (m > M || n > N)
{
    printf("\n\tExcessive matrix size! "), system("pause"), exit(0);
}
printf("\n\tEnter a,b: ");
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
if (a > b)
{
    printf("\n\tThe value of the initial spacing can not be greater than the 
last one! "), system("pause"), exit(0);
}
//Генерация матрицы
srand(time(NULL));
printf("\n\tMatrix Q:\n");    //матрица Q
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        Q[i][j] = rand() % (b - a) + a;
        printf("%5d", Q[i][j]);
    }
}
//Готовая матрица
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Стоит метка `c++`, хотя код написан на чистом `c`. Определитесь.

Comment: А если не секрет, зачем вы вводите две размерности **квадратной** матрицы? `scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);`? А менять - очень просто: идете и обмениваете по одному элементу...

Comment: Сначала я ввожу размерность квадратной матрицы, а потом промежутки, откуда брать числа. Вроде так.

Comment: @VadimLavrov Какими **двумя** параметрами вы описываете квадратную матрицу? Может ли быть квадратная матрица 5x4?

Comment: @Harry черт, опять ошибка. Матрица должна быть любой размерности, хоть 100х100. Главное, что бы менялись столбики и строки.

Comment: Вы никак не хотите сообразить, что в квадратной матрице количество столбцов равно количеству строк, так что не нужно запрашивать **два** числа в качестве размера...

Comment: @Harry Значит, надо запросить одно число, которое будет и значить, какая размерность матрицы будет? N=3, значит автоматически M=3 и матрица будет 3х3? Так я вас понимаю?

Comment: Ну наконец-то :) Теперь можете переходить к следующей части...

Comment: @Harry я вроде как понял. Есть кусочек кода на чистом C, который как по мне, может помочь с моей задачей. Куда его можно пристроить в мой код? https://pastebin.com/WAis6NWU

Comment: Ну, это уже совсем третий вопрос :)

Comment: Вы поменять местами значения двух переменных можете? Со строками/столбцами все то же самое, но только менять местами надо несколько раз.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов нет, еще не умею такое делать(